# Get Steam games of a certain genre

Tags: steam-web-api

I know about the Steam API call: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002

That returns all apps on Steam. But what GET call must I make to return only games of a specified genre?

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there.

You just need to append your API call with query parameters.

Like so:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?tag=RPG
```

Test: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?tag=RPG

or return multiple with:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?tag=Casual&tag=Simulation
```

Test:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?tag=Casual&tag=Simulation

Here are the list of Genre tags:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/tags

References:

- https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api
- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API
- https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/tags

Comment: I tried that RPG URL but I think it returns all apps, or at least it includes apps that lack the RPG tag. One app it returned was this for example: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=1158990. In my case, I'd like to narrow games specifically by genre. In that URL for app 1158990, there's a "genres" property in the resulting JSON.

Comment: The publisher may have tagged it wrong or with multiple tags.

Comment: Try a capital T on tag

Comment: Capital T yields an empty JSON object: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?Tag=RPG

Comment: The `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/` url does not support any filtering, refer to https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps#GetAppList
`Gets the complete list of public apps. This call has no additional parameters.`